# angular anchor routerlink dynamic link address

Tags: angular, anchor, routerlink

In the example below, the selectedDropdown has various subparameters including "dropdown", which contains the "title" and the "router link".
I've tried a variety of ways to supply the routerLink and none work.
[image]
The nxtLink.LinkRoute has valid entries, but I can't get them to show up in the anchor html.

If you could kindly - not only show me how it is supposed to work - but perhaps a short explanation, that would help a lot.

Thanks in advance, Yogi

Comment: Please do not use images, post your code in the answer instead. Also, it'll be easier if you provide a working stackblitz of your scenario so that it can be easily reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried like this :

```
<div class="col-md-3" *ng-for="#display of displays">
    <a [routerLink]="getURL(nxLink.LinkRoute)" >{{ nxLink.linkTitle}}</a>
</div>
```

in your component define method :

```
getURL(link) { 
    return ['/', link];
}
```